# Change the textbox header color in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to change the color of the Textbox header in UWP.
My Textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbFullName" Header="Full Name" Margin="30,24,0,0" MaxLength="320" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" InputScope="PersonalFullName" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

My current (not working) code to change the color:

```
tbFullName.Header = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
```

I hope someone is able to help.
Note: I'm am very new to UWP and I'm quite new to programming, I would really appreciate if the answers given to me aren't all too hard to understand.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will need to edit the Control template, use a simpler approach, or maybe even build your own UWP Custom Control

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585582/gtk-c-sharp-widget-change-color-not-working please check this page. I hope, it give idea to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could custom TextBox's `HeaderTemplate` like the follow.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" Header="Name" >
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
</TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
```

And modify the Foreground the for `TextBlock` that contained in DataTemplate.

**Update**
The foreground theme resource of `HeaderContentPresenter` is `TextControlHeaderForeground` you could also override it in app resource like the follow

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlHeaderForeground" Color="Red" />
</Application.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```
<TextBox Text="Cotent" Height="100" Header="Name"/>
```

[image]